# (qualify for) and (qualify [as]) an excuse

Tags: word-usage

I'd like to know if I could use "**qualify for**" in the context below, with the meaning of "**to give the right to do something**":

Example:

> The abuse of some does not qualify for the tough and unnecessary restrictions.

[Wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/qualify) has this meaning but does not give an example of use:

> "to get authority, license, power, etc., as by fulfilling required
>   conditions, taking an oath, etc."

And what if I'd like to use the word *reason*? I am not sure about dropping the word "**as**":

> The abuse of some doe not qualify [as] an excuse to set the tough and
>   unnecessary restrictions.

The use of **as** has the meaning to fit a description in the dictionary entry below. My usage is fine as far as I can see.

Oxford Collocations Dictionary, 2nd edition

> qualify 
>   verb
>
> 1 have/give sb the right to sth
>
> PREPOSITION
>
> ▪ **for**
>
> ▪ You will automatically qualify for a pension.
>
> 3 **fit a description**
>
> PREPOSITION
>
> ▪ **as**
>
> ▪ A three-week course hardly qualifies as sufficient training.

**Note:** I suppose I could say:

"*The abuse of some doe not justify the tough and unnecessary restrictions*" and be done with it but I'd like to learn how to use qualify. I might need to paraphrase in when writing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use "**qualify for**" in this case. Even though meaning #1 is close to what you want in your sentence, the subject of "qualify for" must also be the recipient of the object. In the dictionary example:

> You will automatically qualify for a pension

"You" is the subject and the recipient of the pension.

In your original sentence that is not the case - the abuse (the subject) isn't the recipient of tough and unnecessary restrictions.

In your second sentence:

> The abuse of some does not qualify as an excuse to set the tough and
>   unnecessary restrictions.

The usage is correct because the abuse (the subject) is the excuse. Note how changing the preposition changes the meaning.